# Cannot use mysqli in php flex env on app engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, mysqli, google-cloud-sql

I recently switched from a standard env to a flex env, so that I could use sockets in my php app. However, now my `mysqli` function is not working when deployed...

This is what the function and error call looks like...

```
    $link = new mysqli(
                    null,                                                   // host
                    'user',                                             // username
                    null,                                                       // password
                    'db',                                           // database name
                    null,
                    '/cloudsql/myapp:us-central1:sql-instance'      // instance name
                );
```

Am I missing something? Can I use `mysqli` in a flex env?  Here are the error logs...

```
    2017-06-22 21:40:16 admin[20170622t152917]  172.17.0.1 - - [22/Jun/2017:21:40:16 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36"
    2017-06-22 21:40:17 admin[20170622t152917]  "GET /" 499
    2017-06-22 21:40:21 admin[20170622t152917]  "POST /app/template_tabs.php" 499
    2017-06-22 21:40:29 admin[20170622t151722]  "GET /MyAdmin/scripts/setup.php" 404
    2017-06-22 21:40:29 admin[20170622t151722]  "GET /db/scripts/setup.php" 404
    2017-06-22 21:40:29 admin[20170622t151722]  "GET /myadmin/scripts/setup.php" 404
    2017-06-22 21:40:29 admin[20170622t151722]  "GET /mysql/scripts/setup.php" 404
    2017-06-22 21:40:29 admin[20170622t151722]  "GET /mysqladmin/scripts/setup.php" 404
    2017-06-22 21:40:29 admin[20170622t151722]  "GET /p/m/a/scripts/setup.php" 404
    2017-06-22 21:40:29 admin[20170622t151722]  "GET /php-my-admin/scripts/setup.php" 404
    2017-06-22 21:40:29 admin[20170622t151722]  "GET /phpMyAdmin-2.2.6/scripts/setup.php" 404
    2017-06-22 21:40:29 admin[20170622t151722]  "GET /phpMyAdmin-2.5.1/scripts/setup.php" 404
    2017-06-22 21:40:29 admin[20170622t151722]  "GET /phpMyAdmin-2.5.5-rc2/scripts/setup.php" 404
    2017-06-22 21:40:29 admin[20170622t151722]  "GET /phpMyAdmin-2.5.6-rc1/scripts/setup.php" 404
    2017-06-22 21:40:29 admin[20170622t151722]  "GET /phpMyAdmin-2.5.6-rc2/scripts/setup.php" 404
    2017-06-22 21:40:29 admin[20170622t151722]  "GET /phpMyAdmin-2.6.0-alpha/scripts/setup.php" 404
    2017-06-22 21:40:29 admin[20170622t151722]  "GET /phpMyAdmin-2.6.0-alpha2/scripts/setup.php" 404
    2017-06-22 21:40:29 admin[20170622t151722]  "GET /phpMyAdmin-2.6.0-rc3/scripts/setup.php" 404
    2017-06-22 21:40:29 admin[20170622t151722]  "GET /phpMyAdmin-2.6.0/scripts/setup.php" 404
    2017-06-22 21:40:29 admin[20170622t151722]  "GET /phpMyAdmin-2.6.1-pl1/scripts/setup.php" 404
    2017-06-22 21:40:29 admin[20170622t151722]  "GET /phpMyAdmin-2.6.1-pl3/scripts/setup.php" 404
    2017-06-22 21:40:29 admin[20170622t151722]  "GET /phpMyAdmin-2.6.2-beta1/scripts/setup.php" 404
    2017-06-22 21:40:29 admin[20170622t151722]  "GET /phpMyAdmin-2.6.2/scripts/setup.php" 404
    2017-06-22 21:40:29 admin[20170622t151722]  "GET /phpMyAdmin-2.6.3/scripts/setup.php" 404
    2017-06-22 21:40:29 admin[20170622t151722]  "GET /phpMyAdmin-2.6.4-pl4/scripts/setup.php" 404
    2017-06-22 21:40:29 admin[20170622t151722]  "GET /phpMyAdmin-2.7.0-pl1/scripts/setup.php" 404
    2017-06-22 21:40:29 admin[20170622t151722]  "GET /phpMyAdmin-2.7.0-rc1/scripts/setup.php" 404
    2017-06-22 21:40:29 admin[20170622t151722]  "GET /phpMyAdmin-2.8.0-beta1/scripts/setup.php" 404
    2017-06-22 21:40:29 admin[20170622t151722]  "GET /phpMyAdmin-2.8.0.3/scripts/setup.php" 404
    2017-06-22 21:40:29 admin[20170622t151722]  "GET /phpMyAdmin-2.8.0/scripts/setup.php" 404
    2017-06-22 21:40:29 admin[20170622t151722]  "GET /phpMyAdmin-2/scripts/setup.php" 404
    2017-06-22 21:40:29 admin[20170622t151722]  "GET /phpMyAdmin/scripts/setup.php" 404
    2017-06-22 21:40:29 admin[20170622t151722]  "GET /phpadmin/scripts/setup.php" 404
    2017-06-22 21:40:29 admin[20170622t151722]  "GET /phpmanager/scripts/setup.php" 404
    2017-06-22 21:40:29 admin[20170622t151722]  "GET /phpmyadmin/scripts/setup.php" 404
    2017-06-22 21:40:29 admin[20170622t151722]  "GET /phpmyadmin1/scripts/setup.php" 404
    2017-06-22 21:40:29 admin[20170622t151722]  "GET /phpmyadmin2/scripts/setup.php" 404
    2017-06-22 21:40:29 admin[20170622t151722]  "GET /pma2005/scripts/setup.php" 404
    2017-06-22 21:40:29 admin[20170622t151722]  "GET /scripts/setup.php" 404
    2017-06-22 21:40:29 admin[20170622t151722]  "GET /sqlweb/scripts/setup.php" 404
    2017-06-22 21:40:29 admin[20170622t151722]  "GET /web/phpMyAdmin/scripts/setup.php" 404
    2017-06-22 21:40:29 admin[20170622t151722]  "GET /web/scripts/setup.php" 404
    2017-06-22 21:40:29 admin[20170622t151722]  "GET /websql/scripts/setup.php" 404
    2017-06-22 21:41:11 admin[20170622t152917]  [22-Jun-2017 21:41:11] WARNING: [pool app] child 36 said into stderr: "NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Warning:  mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): Connection timed out in /app/php/cons.php on line 25"
    2017-06-22 21:41:11 admin[20170622t152917]  [22-Jun-2017 21:41:11] WARNING: [pool app] child 36 said into stderr: "NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Warning:  mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /app/app/body.php on line 4"
    2017-06-22 21:41:11 admin[20170622t152917]  [22-Jun-2017 21:41:11] WARNING: [pool app] child 36 said into stderr: "NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Warning:  mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /app/app/body.php on line 7"
    2017-06-22 21:41:11 admin[20170622t152917]  [22-Jun-2017 21:41:11] WARNING: [pool app] child 36 said into stderr: "NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /app/app/body.php on line 26"
    2017-06-22 21:41:11 admin[20170622t152917]  [22-Jun-2017 21:41:11] WARNING: [pool app] child 36 said into stderr: "NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /app/app/body.php on line 59"
    2017-06-22 21:41:12 admin[20170622t152917]  [22-Jun-2017 21:41:12] WARNING: [pool app] child 37 said into stderr: "NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Warning:  mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /app/app/body.php on line 4"
    2017-06-22 21:41:12 admin[20170622t152917]  [22-Jun-2017 21:41:12] WARNING: [pool app] child 37 said into stderr: "NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Warning:  mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /app/app/body.php on line 7"
    2017-06-22 21:41:12 admin[20170622t152917]  [22-Jun-2017 21:41:12] WARNING: [pool app] child 37 said into stderr: "NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /app/app/body.php on line 26"
    2017-06-22 21:41:12 admin[20170622t152917]  [22-Jun-2017 21:41:12] WARNING: [pool app] child 37 said into stderr: "NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /app/app/body.php on line 59"
    2017-06-22 21:41:12 admin[20170622t152917]  PHP message: PHP Warning:  mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /app/app/body.php on line 4
    2017-06-22 21:41:12 admin[20170622t152917]  PHP message: PHP Warning:  mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /app/app/body.php on line 7
    2017-06-22 21:41:12 admin[20170622t152917]  PHP message: PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /app/app/body.php on line 26
    2017-06-22 21:41:12 admin[20170622t152917]  172.17.0.1 - - [22/Jun/2017:21:41:12 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2404 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36"
    2017-06-22 21:41:12 admin[20170622t152917]  PHP message: PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /app/app/body.php on line 59" while reading response header from upstream, client: 172.17.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "admin-dot-appdocs-com.appspot.com"
    2017-06-22 21:41:17 admin[20170622t152917]  "GET /" 200
    2017-06-22 21:41:17 admin[20170622t152917]  "GET /favicon.ico" 200
```

Comment: the `mysqli` command runs locally. when I run `php -S localhost:8080 -t ./`

Answer (score 2):

Add a file `php.ini` with the following:

```
mysqli.default_socket= '/cloudsql/CONNECTION_NAME'
```

Also make sure the `sqladmin` API is enabled:
https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/sqladmin.googleapis.com/overview

Comment: hey can you point me to the documentation that details the `mysqli.default_socket` rule in the `php.ini`.   I want to see the format of the `connection_name`

Comment: It's just a file path. You can get the CONNECTION_NAME from the cloud sql detail page in the cloud console. It should say "Instance connection name"